# PHP curl -- get POST fields on instantiated curl resource?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Is there any way to retrieve the POST fields set on a curl resource?

e.g.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);`

Is there any way to retrieve the `$payload` from `$ch`?

I've seen `curl_getinfo`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php but it doesn't seem to return such data.

Comment: You need to do this on same script? Or, actually, remote script you sending data to?

Comment: Same script... the curl resource is a class property and there are a few methods that can set data/options on it. I'd like to retrieve all the options and POST data from it before sending the request so I can log it out if debugging is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Even with `curl_getinfo`, you wouldn't be able to extract the POST data until after the request was issued.

Based on your comment it sounds like your code is making the `curl_setopt` calls, but that you have a few places that do this?

How about a thin wrapper for setting POST vars

```
class SomeClient {
  private $post_vars = array();
  private $ch;

  private function _curl_setpostvar(array $post_vars) {
    $this->post_vars = array_merge($this->post_vars, $post_vars);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);
  }
}
```

Now your other instance methods can substitute `_curl_setpostvar` in place of `curl_setopt` when setting POST vars on the handle.

The POST vars will be available via `$this->post_vars`, even before the request is sent.

Answer (score 1):

The only way seems to use [`CURLOPT_PRIVATE`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) property when setting data and then retrieve manually by that key.

Answer (score 0):

I might assume that there is no easy way of doing it. If you need this data for debugging I'd rather suggest working with an array in your class, setting it like:

```
$options = array( 
    //other cURL properties...
    CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $curl_data,
    //other cURL properties...
);
```

and then binding it to **cURL** descriptor with `curl_setopt_array($ch, $options)` just before `curl_exec($ch)`.